# Can I alter this php mail() function to stop it sending mail to outlooks Junk

Tags: php, email, outlook

I have this mail function that works fine, except that it always arrives in outlooks "junk".

Can I change anything to make it arrive in the "inbox"?

Also I'm not sure if it is related but sometimes it takes some time to arrive and sometimes it doesn't seem to arrive?

code:

```
$subject = 'subject';
        $message = 'testingyesyes';
        $to = 'mail@chrismepham.com';
        $type = 'plain'; // or HTML
        $charset = 'utf-8';

        $mail     = 'no-reply@'.str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        $uniqid   = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $headers  = 'From: '.$mail."\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-to: '.$mail."\n";
        $headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$mail."\n";
        $headers .= 'Message-ID: <'.$uniqid.'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
        $headers .= 'Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())."\n";
        $headers .= 'X-Priority: 1'."\n";
        $headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: High'."\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="----------'.$uniqid.'"'."\n\n";
        $headers .= '------------'.$uniqid."\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/'.$type.';charset='.$charset.''."\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit';

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, outlook is very strict in what it looks for in an e-mail (similar to hotmail). I've had plain text- PHP e-mails go in junk before because they have some keywords that they don't like.

Comment: My guess is that, if you don't have `no-reply@yourDomain.com` on your system, Outlook throws it out. It probably tries to sniff out if an actual `From` email address exists and if not, Bzzzt. Try using your own email address to test it out, and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out following links

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/how-gmail-and-other-mail-services-detects-a-mail-as-a-spam

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-spam-filters-think